# how to calculate the correlation matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, correlation

I have a data set which is showed below;

```
x1          x2          x3
-10.593017  NaN         NaN
-10.300049  3.624823938 NaN
-11.776855  3.707569866 NaN
-10.342041  3.770059949 NaN
-19.416992  3.819520417 6.516808442
-12.051026  3.898067841 6.753639662
NaN         3.687338806 6.317082898
NaN         NaN         6.226243427
```

can you tell me how to calculate the correlation matrix? can 'corrcoef' be used in the program? or there are other methods. please tell me. thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please reformat your question so that it fits the SO FAQ standards. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: You can calculate correlation between `x1` and `x2` as `corr2(x1,x2)`. Similarly you can calculate for other pairs. Is this what you want? You will have to take care of `NaN`s

Answer (score 7):

You can use either [CORR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corr.html) or [CORRCOEF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html) functions. Both functions will return the same correlation matrix (the results may differ for very low p-values depending on your MATLAB release).

You need to take care of NaN values. Both have parameter `'rows'`. Here is a quote from documentation with possible parameter values:

> Either 'all' (default) to use all rows, 'complete' to use rows with no
>   NaN values, or 'pairwise' to compute R(i,j) using rows with no NaN
>   values in either column i or j.

If you have NaN elements setting `'rows'` to `'all '` will use all the elements, but you will get NaN as a results. `'complete'` will use only rows without NaN in any columns. `'pairwise'` is what I usually use, it will remove the rows with NaN for each comparison independently.

So, if you `x1`, `x2` and `x3` are column vectors to get correlation matrix use:

```
[rho, pval] = corr([x1, x2, x3], 'rows','pairwise');
```

If your variables are columns in one matrix `x`:

```
[rho, pval] = corr(x, 'rows','pairwise');
```

Or use `corrcoef` instead of `corr`. CORR can also calculate other than Pearson correlation, like Spearman or Kendall. Specify it with `'type'` parameter.